# Understanding Error in nls2 and as.lm functions

Tags: r, curve-fitting, nls

I was doing a fit of a function and I came across some problems related to the errors estimated by the methodology used.

The function I was trying fit is `y=o/(x*(x+t)^k)`

First of all, here is first part of the code including functions definitions to do the fit:

```
## librarys

    library(nls2)
    library(magicaxis)

y=c(133129.8,132171.4,131439,130849.8,130359.6,129942.2,129580.6,129263.1,128981.5,128729.6,128498.8,128281.9,128075.8,127878.4,127687.7,127502.7,127322.7,127146.5,126973.2,126802.1,126633.3,126467.2,126303.2,126140.8,125979.4,125810.1,125624.4,125421.6,125201.5,124964.2,124714.1,124455.8,124189.3,123914.4,123631.3,123344.3,123057.8,122772,122486.6,122201.4,121912.2,121614.8,121309,120994.6,120671.7,120342.6,120009.5,119672.4,119331.4,118986.2,118633.9,118271.9,117899.8,117517.8,117125.6,116722.6,116307.9,115881.4,115443.2,114993.2,114532.4,114061.5,113580.5,113089.6,112588.5,112077.1,111554.7,111021.5,110477.4,109922.4,109357.6,108783.8,108201.2,107609.6,107009.2,106400.9,105785.7,105163.6,104534.7,103898.9,103256.2,102606.4,101949.6,101285.7,100614.8,99936.8,99251.7,98559.5,97860.2,97153.8,96441.3,95723.7,95001,94273.3,93540.4,92804.5,92067.2,91328.6,90588.8,89847.8,89106.5,88365.8,87625.7,86886.3,86147.6,85412.2,84682.6,83958.8,83240.9,82528.8,81821,81116,80413.8,79714.3,79017.5,78324.4,77635.7,76951.3,76271.4,75596,74925.8,74261.6,73603.4,72951.2,72305.1,71665.8,71034,70409.8,69793.2,69184,68581,67983,67389.9,66801.6,66218.1,65636.9,65055.4,64473.7,63891.5,63309.1,62727.6,62148.3,61571.3,60996.6,60424,59853.1,59283.2,58714.4,58146.6,57579.9,57014.7,56451.7,55891,55332.4,54776,54222.4,53672.1,53125,52581.2,52040.7,51504,50971.7,50443.6,49919.8,49400.3,48885.7,48376.2,47872.1,47373.2,46879.6,46392.7,45914.1,45443.7,44981.5,44527.5,44081.2,43641.9,43209.7,42784.4,42366.2,41954.4,41548.4,41148.3,40754,40365.4,39982.1,39603.5,39229.4,38860,38495.1,38135.3,37780.6,37431.3,37087.3,36748.5,36415.3,36088,35766.6,35451.1,35141.4,34837,34537.3,34242.3,33952,33666.4,33385.7,33110.1,32839.8,32574.7,32314.7,32059.4,31808,31560.6,31317.2,31077.8,30843.4,30615.1,30392.8,30176.5,29966.4,29762.4,29564.9,29373.9,29189.3,29011.1,28839.1,28673.2,28513.2,28359.2,28211.2,28068.6,27930.7,27797.7,27669.3,27545.7,27425.5,27307.3,27191.1,27077,26964.8,26854.8,26747.1,26641.5,26538.2,26437.2,26339.2,26245.1,26154.8,26068.5,25985.9,25906.6,25829.9,25755.9,25684.4,25615.5,25548.9,25484.4,25421.9,25361.4,25302.9,25246.1,25190.8,25136.8,25084.3,25033.1,24982.7,24932.5,24882.3,24832.3,24782.3,24732.8,24684.1,24636.1,24588.8,24542.3,24496.1,24450.1,24404.1,24358.2,24312.3,24266.1,24219.3,24171.8,24123.6,24074.8,24025.3,23974.9,23923.8,23871.9,23819.2,23765.9,23712.3,23658.3,23603.9,23549.2,23494.1,23438.3,23382,23325.1,23267.7,23210.1,23152.9,23096,23039.5,22983.3,22926.7,22869.1,22810.3,22750.4,22689.5,22627.5,22564.7,22501,22436.4,22371,22305,22238.9,22172.7,22106.3,22039.8,21973.6,21907.8,21842.6,21777.9,21713.8,21650,21586.3,21522.6,21459.1,21395.6,21332.5,21270,21208.2,21147.1,21086.5,21026.9,20968.5,20911.2,20855,20800,20746.2,20693.4,20641.7,20591.1,20541.6,20492.8,20444.6,20396.8,20349.5,20302.7,20256.2,20210.1,20164.3,20118.8,20073.6,20028.9,19984.8,19941.3,19898.4,19856.2,19814.6,19773.9,19734.1,19695.1,19657,19619.8,19583.6,19548.5,19514.4,19481.3,19449.4,19418.6,19389,19360.6,19333.4,19307.3,19282.6,19259.1,19236.8,19215.8,19195.8,19176.7,19158.5,19141,19124.4,19108.6,19093.7,19079.5,19066.2,19053.7,19042,19031.1,19020.9,19011.4,19002.7,18994.7,18987.4,18980.7,18974.6,18969.2,18964.4,18960,18956,18952.5,18949.4,18946.7,18944.5,18942.7,18941.3,18940.3,18939.8,18939.8,18940.1,18940.9 )
    
        x=c(0.003,0.004,0.005,0.006,0.007,0.008,0.009,0.01,0.011,0.012,0.013,0.014,0.015,0.016,0.017,0.018,0.019,0.02,0.021,0.022,0.023,0.024,0.025,0.026,0.027,0.028,0.029,0.03,0.031,0.032,0.033,0.034,0.035,0.036,0.037,0.038,0.039,0.04,0.041,0.042,0.043,0.044,0.045,0.046,0.047,0.048,0.049,0.05,0.051,0.052,0.053,0.054,0.055,0.056,0.057,0.058,0.059,0.06,0.061,0.062,0.063,0.064,0.065,0.066,0.067,0.068,0.069,0.07,0.071,0.072,0.073,0.074,0.075,0.076,0.077,0.078,0.079,0.08,0.081,0.082,0.083,0.084,0.085,0.086,0.087,0.088,0.089,0.09,0.091,0.092,0.093,0.094,0.095,0.096,0.097,0.098,0.099,0.1,0.101,0.102,0.103,0.104,0.105,0.106,0.107,0.108,0.109,0.11,0.111,0.112,0.113,0.114,0.115,0.116,0.117,0.118,0.119,0.12,0.121,0.122,0.123,0.124,0.125,0.126,0.127,0.128,0.129,0.13,0.131,0.132,0.133,0.134,0.135,0.136,0.137,0.138,0.139,0.14,0.141,0.142,0.143,0.144,0.145,0.146,0.147,0.148,0.149,0.15,0.151,0.152,0.153,0.154,0.155,0.156,0.157,0.158,0.159,0.16,0.161,0.162,0.163,0.164,0.165,0.166,0.167,0.168,0.169,0.17,0.171,0.172,0.173,0.174,0.175,0.176,0.177,0.178,0.179,0.18,0.181,0.182,0.183,0.184,0.185,0.186,0.187,0.188,0.189,0.19,0.191,0.192,0.193,0.194,0.195,0.196,0.197,0.198,0.199,0.2,0.201,0.202,0.203,0.204,0.205,0.206,0.207,0.208,0.209,0.21,0.211,0.212,0.213,0.214,0.215,0.216,0.217,0.218,0.219,0.22,0.221,0.222,0.223,0.224,0.225,0.226,0.227,0.228,0.229,0.23,0.231,0.232,0.233,0.234,0.235,0.236,0.237,0.238,0.239,0.24,0.241,0.242,0.243,0.244,0.245,0.246,0.247,0.248,0.249,0.25,0.251,0.252,0.253,0.254,0.255,0.256,0.257,0.258,0.259,0.26,0.261,0.262,0.263,0.264,0.265,0.266,0.267,0.268,0.269,0.27,0.271,0.272,0.273,0.274,0.275,0.276,0.277,0.278,0.279,0.28,0.281,0.282,0.283,0.284,0.285,0.286,0.287,0.288,0.289,0.29,0.291,0.292,0.293,0.294,0.295,0.296,0.297,0.298,0.299,0.3,0.301,0.302,0.303,0.304,0.305,0.306,0.307,0.308,0.309,0.31,0.311,0.312,0.313,0.314,0.315,0.316,0.317,0.318,0.319,0.32,0.321,0.322,0.323,0.324,0.325,0.326,0.327,0.328,0.329,0.33,0.331,0.332,0.333,0.334,0.335,0.336,0.337,0.338,0.339,0.34,0.341,0.342,0.343,0.344,0.345,0.346,0.347,0.348,0.349,0.35,0.351,0.352,0.353,0.354,0.355,0.356,0.357,0.358,0.359,0.36,0.361,0.362,0.363,0.364,0.365,0.366,0.367,0.368,0.369,0.37,0.371,0.372,0.373,0.374,0.375,0.376,0.377,0.378,0.379,0.38,0.381,0.382,0.383,0.384,0.385,0.386,0.387,0.388,0.389,0.39,0.391,0.392,0.393,0.394,0.395,0.396,0.397,0.398,0.399,0.4,0.401,0.402,0.403,0.404,0.405,0.406,0.407,0.408,0.409,0.41,0.411,0.412,0.413,0.414,0.415,0.416 )

########### functions used for carry out the fit ########
    
## this function is avaible in: 
# http://www.leg.ufpr.br/~walmes/cursoR/ciaeear/as.lm.R   or in 
# https://gist.github.com/TonyLadson/2d63ca70eef92583001dece607127759 (from the line 269)

##### as.lm function:

        as.lm <- function(object, ...) UseMethod("as.lm")
        
        as.lm.nls <- function(object, ...) {
            if (!inherits(object, "nls")) {
                w <- paste("expected object of class nls but got object of class:", 
                    paste(class(object), collapse = " "))
                warning(w)
            }
        
            gradient <- object$m$gradient()
            if (is.null(colnames(gradient))) {
                colnames(gradient) <- names(object$m$getPars())
            }
        
            response.name <- if (length(formula(object)) == 2) "0" else 
                as.character(formula(object)[[2]])
        
            lhs <- object$m$lhs()
            L <- data.frame(lhs, gradient)
            names(L)[1] <- response.name
        
            fo <- sprintf("%s ~ %s - 1", response.name, 
                paste(colnames(gradient), collapse = "+"))
            fo <- as.formula(fo, env = as.proto.list(L))
        
            do.call("lm", list(fo, offset = substitute(fitted(object))))
        
        }

############## End as.lm function ####################

#### proto function avaible in https://github.com/hadley/proto/blob/master/R/proto.R

##### proto function:

proto <- function(. = parent.env(envir), expr = {},
                   envir = new.env(parent = parent.frame()), ...,
                   funEnvir = envir) {
  parent.env(envir) <- .
  envir <- as.proto.environment(envir)  # must do this before eval(...)
  # moved eval after for so that ... always done first
  # eval(substitute(eval(quote({ expr }))), envir)
  dots <- list(...); names <- names(dots)
  for (i in seq_along(dots)) {
    assign(names[i], dots[[i]], envir = envir)
    if (!identical(funEnvir, FALSE) && is.function(dots[[i]]))
      environment(envir[[names[i]]]) <- funEnvir
  }
  eval(substitute(eval(quote({
    expr
  }))), envir)
  if (length(dots))
    as.proto.environment(envir)
  else
    envir
}

#' @export
#' @rdname proto
as.proto <- function(x, ...) {
  UseMethod("as.proto")
}

#' @export
#' @rdname proto
as.proto.environment <- function(x, ...) {
  assign(".that", x, envir = x)
  assign(".super", parent.env(x), envir = x)
  structure(x, class = c("proto", "environment"))
}

#' @export
#' @rdname proto
as.proto.proto <- function(x, ...) {
  x
}
as.proto.list <- function(x, envir, parent, all.names = FALSE, ...,
                          funEnvir = envir, SELECT = function(x) TRUE) {
  if (missing(envir)) {
    if (missing(parent))
      parent <- parent.frame()
    envir <- if (is.proto(parent))
      parent$proto(...)
    else
      proto(parent, ...)
  }
  for (s in names(x))
    if (SELECT(x[[s]])) {
      assign(s, x[[s]], envir = envir)
      if (is.function(x[[s]]) && !identical(funEnvir, FALSE))
        environment(envir[[s]]) <- funEnvir
    }
  if (!missing(parent))
    parent.env(envir) <- parent
  as.proto.environment(envir)  # force refresh of .that and .super
}

#' @export
"$<-.proto" <- function(this,s,value) {
  if (s == ".super")
    parent.env(this) <- value
  if (is.function(value))
    environment(value) <- this
  this[[as.character(substitute(s))]] <- value
  this
}
is.proto <- function(x) inherits(x, "proto")

#' @export
"$.proto" <- function(x, name) {
  inherits <- substr(name, 1, 2) != ".."

  res <- get(name, envir = x, inherits = inherits)
  if (!is.function(res))
    return(res)

  if (deparse(substitute(x)) %in% c(".that", ".super"))
    return(res)

  structure(
    function(...) res(x, ...),
    class = "protoMethod",
    method = res
  )
}

#' @export
print.protoMethod <- function(x, ...) {
  cat("<ProtoMethod>\n")
  print(attr(x, "method"), ...)
}

# modified from Tom Short's original
#' @export
str.proto <- function(object, max.level = 1, nest.lev = 0,
                      indent.str = paste(rep.int(" ", max(0, nest.lev + 1)), collapse = ".."),
                      ...) {
  cat("proto", name.proto(object), "\n")
  Lines <- utils::capture.output(utils::str(
    as.list(object), max.level = max.level,
    nest.lev = nest.lev, ...
  ))[-1]
  for (s in Lines)
    cat(s, "\n")
  if (is.proto(parent.env(object))) {
    cat(indent.str, "parent: ", sep = "")
    utils::str(parent.env(object), nest.lev = nest.lev + 1, ...)
  }
}

#' @export
print.proto <- function(x, ...) {
  if (!exists("proto_print", envir = x, inherits = TRUE))
    return(NextMethod())

  x$proto_print(...)
}

############# End proto function ##############

################# Finally doing the fit ##############
#################                       ##############

     start_ini=data.frame(t=c(0.1,1),o=c(10,1000),k=c(2,3))
    
        py=nls2(y ~ o/(x*(x+t)^k), start=start_ini, algorithm="brute-force")
        
        summary(py)
    
    Results:
    
        > Formula: y ~ o/(x * (x + t)^k)
        
        Parameters:
          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
        t     0.70      17.90   0.039    0.969
        o   670.00   23162.61   0.029    0.977
        k     2.00      46.48   0.043    0.966
        
        Residual standard error: 55100 on 411 degrees of freedom
        
        Number of iterations to convergence: 64 
        Achieved convergence tolerance: NA
```

Obtained the values and figure from the fit:

```
predfit=data.frame(predict(as.lm(py), interval="confidence", level=0.95))

##### figures #######

### only points
magplot(x,y,log='xy',pch=20,col="gray",cex=1.5)
### curve fitted on the points 
lines(x,predfit$fit,log='xy',col='red',lwd=2)
```

[image]

Visually, the fit its reasonable (very good for me in view the others fits), however the errors `Std. Error` did not decrease significantly (are not of the same order of magnitude of the values found).

Still, when I do `summary(as.lm(py))`, I obtain:

`summary(as.lm(py))`

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ t + o + k - 1, offset = fitted(py))

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-9820.4 -5944.9   625.8  5790.9 18081.0 

Coefficients:
   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
t 1.169e+02  2.086e+00   56.05   <2e-16 ***
o 1.629e+05  2.698e+03   60.37   <2e-16 ***
k 2.517e+02  5.414e+00   46.48   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 6419 on 411 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9908,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9908 
F-statistic: 1.479e+04 on 3 and 411 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

My questions are:

1. What happened that the values found by the `summary(as.lm(py))` for the parameters `t`,`o` and `k` were different from those created?
2. How is the `Std. Error` is computed?
3. Is there a way to make the fit better, both in `Std. Error` and in curve in red?
4. It is possible to make the fit by means of a polynomial and then to recover the coefficients `t`,`o` and `k`?
5. Could the errors decrease if I made the fit in a different language?

I tried using a Bayesian approach through the `LaplaceDemons` package but it did not work very well, although the values found for the parameters were very good. But the curve went very far.

Follow:

```
library(LaplacesDemon)

datas = data.frame(x,y)

    nu=function(x, o, t, k){ ### function to be fit
  o/(x * (x + t)^k)  
}

parm.names=as.parm.names(list(o=0, t=0, k=0, sig=0) )

mon.names='LP'

posi_o<-grep("o", parm.names)
posi_t<-grep("t", parm.names)
posi_k<-grep("k", parm.names)
posi_sig<-grep("sig", parm.names)

Data=list(data=datas, mon.names=mon.names, parm.names=parm.names, 
          posi_o=posi_o, posi_t=posi_t, posi_k=posi_k, posi_sig=posi_sig,
          N=nrow(datas))



Model=function(parm, Data) { 
  ### Parameters
  o <- parm[Data$posi_o]
  t <- parm[Data$posi_t]
  k <- interval(parm[Data$posi_k], 0, 3)
  sig <- interval(parm[Data$posi_sig], 0.01, 1e7)
  parm[Data$posi_k] <- k
  parm[Data$posi_sig] <- sig
  ### Log-Prior 
  o_prio<-dunif(o, 0, 4 ,log=TRUE)
  t_prio<-dunif(t, 0.1, 2, log=TRUE)  
  k_prio<-dunif(k, 1, 4, log=TRUE) 
  # 
  LL = sum(dnorm(y, mean = nu(x, o, t, k), sd = sig, log = TRUE))
  LP = LL + o_prio + t_prio + k_prio 
  Modelout=list(LP=LP, Dev=2*LL, Monitor=LP, yhat=nu(x, o, t, k), parm=parm)
}

Initial.Values=c(1, 0.1 ,1, 1)

FitLF=LaplacesDemon(Model, Data, Initial.Values=Initial.Values , 
                    Algorithm='HARM', Iterations = 1e5)


    print(FitLF$Summary1)
   
>                   Mean           SD         MCSE        ESS            LB        Median
o         3.656502e+00 3.412755e-01 6.928959e-02  34.084181  2.775002e+00  3.744058e+00
t         1.439476e-01 2.933259e-02 1.300266e-03 549.174723  1.139509e-01  1.463333e-01
k         2.913904e+00 1.003414e-01 1.294336e-02 123.973686  2.629820e+00  2.951322e+00
sig       9.388800e+01 3.165280e+01 1.054591e+01   2.384864  2.332303e+01  9.686648e+01
Deviance -4.534286e+08 1.636949e+09 3.126983e+08  60.549855 -2.874984e+09 -1.571863e+08
LP       -2.267143e+08 8.184746e+08 1.563491e+08  60.549855 -1.437492e+09 -7.859314e+07
                    UB
o         3.989927e+00
t         1.557794e-01
k         2.999177e+00
sig       1.371025e+02
Deviance -7.843105e+07
LP       -3.921553e+07


o_esti=FitLF$Summary1[1,'Mean'] 
k_esti=FitLF$Summary1[3,'Mean'] 
t_esti=FitLF$Summary1[2,'Mean']


########## figure

    magplot(x,y,log='xy',pch=20,col="gray",cex=1.5, ylim=range(nu(x, o_esti, t_esti,  k_esti)) )
    
    lines( x ,nu(x, o_esti, k_esti, t_esti), log='xy', col="red" )
```

[image]

Comment: Dear David, I read this and all your past questions on this problem. I think that your model is not sufficiently flexible to adequately fit to your data. Can you change model ?

Comment: Hi Marco, thanks for u attention. I don't know very well if I can chnage the model, because the most important  thing in all this procedure (according to the theory) are the parameters estimated, in this case `t`, `o`  and `k`,  because they're going to tell me what kind of system I'm dealing. So, I believe that I can change model since I can get obtain equivalent parameters to the estimated. I try also, to assign values for the  `k` parameter and expand the denominator in Taylor or binomial series and make a polynomial fit, but the resulting coefficients are very strange..What do you think ?

Comment: as.lm has not been part of the nls2 package for years.